# How to convert a unix timestamp to a Date in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, date, typescript

In plain JavaScript and TypeScript we can write the following to obtain the unix timestamp of a Date:

```
let d = new Date();
const unixtime = d.valueOf();
```

Now, in JavaScript, we can easily convert that unix timestamp back to a Date:

```
d = new Date(unixtime);
```

However, in TypeScript, the above returns an error message:

> error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

So how can I convert a unix timestamp to a date in TypeScript? I'm using ES6 library

Comment: Hm, looks like a correct way to do it in JS and TS. 
Also, [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) generate the same code as JS.

Comment: Odd. Straight from typescripts own [`lib.es6.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L795) it shows that the date constructor has an overload: `new(value: number): Date;`

Answer (score 10):

> in TypeScript, the above returns an error message:

There is no error in current TypeScript:

[image]

## Fix

Update TypeScript to latest

Comment: Weird, I'm using typescript 2.6.2 and node is setup to always download the latest version